# How to use dynamic SQL in SQL Server 2005 to alter login

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a script that works fine in SQL Server 2008R2 but it couldn't work in SQL Server 2005. Is there any way that can work for both version?

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)  = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(DisabledName) + ' DISABLE;'
from [SysAdmin].[dbo].[DisabledAccountHistory]
where DisabledName in (select name 
                       from sys.server_principals 
                       where is_disabled = 0)
group by DisabledName

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0 Cannot assign a default value to a local variable. Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3 Must declare the scalar variable "@SQL". Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'. Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 8 Must declare the scalar variable "@SQL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration including an assignment of an initial value on a single line is a **new feature** in SQL Server 2008 - you cannot do this in 2005.

Change your line to:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) 
set @SQL  = N''
```